# What is a cartesian equation for 3 space passing through 3 points?

Tags: determinant

What does cartesian equation for 3 pace look like?

and is there any way to describe this equation using determinant?

Comment: You mean an equation of a plane?

Comment: yeah i think so

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal P$ is the plane $(ABC)$, then: $M \in \mathcal P \Leftrightarrow \det(\vec{AM},\vec{AB},\vec{AC})=0$